# cygwin dumping stack when reading a file

Tags: c, stack

I'm using cygwin 64 bit for gcc compiler.I'm trying something new with this code and my reading file(covid-19.csv) has about 12600 lines. After about 2250 lines cygwin returns,

```
0 [main] myalgo 872 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to myalgo.exe.stackdump
```

And `ulimit -s` gives only **2032**. Yes, I know this can be done easily with c functions but I wanted to try without using some functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argCount, char *argv[])
{
    char fileName[] = "covid-19.csv";
    int getFields(int, int, char*);
    char* heading; 
    char* subHeading;
    char charTaken;
    int count;
    int arg1 = 1;
    int arg2 = 1;
    char buildStr[25];
    int argument1Col = 0;
    int argument2Col = 0;

    if(argCount != 3)
    {
        printf("invalid amount of arguments\n datalyze [arg1] [arg2]\ndateRep  day  month  year  cases  deaths  countriesAndTerritories  geoId  countryterritoryCode  popData2018  continentExp");
        return(-1);
    }

    heading = argv[1];
    subHeading = argv[2];

    FILE *openFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(openFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("No file can be found %s.", fileName);
        return(-1);
    }

    while(1) 
    { 
        charTaken = fgetc(openFile); 
        if(charTaken == ',')
        {
            buildStr[count] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(buildStr, heading) == 0)
            {
                argument1Col = arg1;
            }

            if(strcmp(buildStr, subHeading) == 0)
            {
                argument2Col = arg2;
            }
            arg1++;
            arg2++;
            count = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if(charTaken == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        buildStr[count] = charTaken; 
        count++;
    } 
    fclose(openFile);

    if(argument1Col == 0 || argument2Col == 0)
    {
        printf("Entered Fields are wrong.\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    if(argument1Col > argument2Col)
    {
        argument1Col = argument1Col + argument2Col;
        argument2Col = argument1Col - argument2Col;
        argument1Col = argument1Col - argument2Col;
    }
        getFields(argument1Col, argument2Col, fileName);

}

int getFields(int field1, int field2, char* fileName)
{
    char c;
    char buildWord[25];
    int count = 0;
    int commaCount = 0;
    FILE *openFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if(openFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("No file can be found %s.", fileName);
        return(-1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(openFile);
        if(c == ',')
        {
            commaCount++;
            if(commaCount == field1)
            {
                buildWord[count] = '\0';
                printf("%s     ", buildWord);
            }
            else if(commaCount == field2)
            {
                buildWord[count] = '\0';
                printf("%s", buildWord);
            }
            count = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            count = 0;
            commaCount = 0;
            printf("\n");
        } 
        if(c == EOF) break;
        buildWord[count] = c;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(openFile);
}
```

The covid-19 file looks like this.

```
dateRep,day,month,year,cases,deaths,countriesAndTerritories,geoId,countryterritoryCode,popData2018,continentExp
23/04/2020,23,4,2020,84,4,Afghanistan,AF,AFG,37172386,Asia
22/04/2020,22,4,2020,61,1,Afghanistan,AF,AFG,37172386,Asia
21/04/2020,21,4,2020,35,2,Afghanistan,AF,AFG,37172386,Asia
20/04/2020,20,4,2020,88,3,Afghanistan,AF,AFG,37172386,Asia
...
...
```

If there is any way to solve this error and read whole file please help.
Thank you.

Comment: `int count; buildStr[count] = '\0';` That results in undefined behaviour because `count` is not initialised.

Comment: regarding: `printf("No file can be found %s.", fileName);`   1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) when the error indication is from a C library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` handles outputting both your error message and the text reason to `stderr`.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  The posted code causes the compiler to output several warning messages.  First, since `argc` and `argv[]` are not used the compiler will output  two warning messages about unused parameters.

Comment: since the file is closed and reopened, the column header line will be the first thing read in the function: `getfields()` which that function does not allow for that event.

Comment: suggest reading about `fgets()` and `strtok()` for processing the input file.

Comment: OT: strongly suggest replacing: `while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(openFile);` with `while( (c = fgetc( openFile ) != EOF )`

Comment: regarding: `c = fgetc(openFile);` and `char c;`  The function `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: OT: regarding the 3 `if()` statements: `if(c == ',')` and `if(c == '\n')` and `if(c == EOF)`  Strongly suggest using a `switch( c )` statement with `case ',`:` `case '\n':` `case EOF:` and `default:`  to help clarify your code.

Comment: Code doesn't give any warnings ```argc``` is used as ```argCount```. What I'm trying to do is when I type on my comand line ```covid day month```(covid is the compiled executable) program should take ```day month``` from the csv file and print only day and month values. It works fine about  2250 lines after that program crashes. I think it is a memory problem. I have no idea about how to increase it.